# Android Default Browser not loading on a particular URL

Tags: android, url, browser, uri

Im doing an automation using monkeyrunner.
The script that I'm doing needs to load URL in the Android Default Browser,
however when I tried to use the URL shown below, the Browser is not loading, and it does not open the browser at all.

http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://ark.com.ge/&ei=IDeoUIPUI-ik0AWa1oCIDg&usg=AFQjCNE1H_KILEGlt8o_ewzUszZUJfMV9A&sig2=Ygg8NBvIiOWFfiziSKFJKA

The question is, what's with this URL, and why is the Browser not working?
the length? the combination of characters?

By the way, this URL is working in the desktop.

Shown below is the part of the code the runs this URL

```
device.wake()
MonkeyRunner.sleep(2)
device.shell('am force-stop com.google.android.browser')
MonkeyRunner.sleep(2)
device.startActivity( component='com.google.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity', uri=url)
MonkeyRunner.sleep(40)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post some code which you have tried to load the above url in your application.

Comment: This url has a redirect. Can you please post the code used.

Comment: @Grishu hi, the question was edited already and now contains the code. Thank you

Comment: @PassionateAndroiden hi, the question was edited already and now contains the code. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Use this code, Its working for me

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://ark.com.ge/&ei=IDeoUIPUI-ik0AWa1oCIDg&usg=AFQjCNE1H_KILEGlt8o_ewzUszZUJfMV9A&sig2=Ygg8NBvIiOWFfiziSKFJKA"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: is this applicable in monkeyrunner as well?

Comment: srh snl asked about monkeyrunner, not about running code from android